# Google Map off center/cutting off

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that is being created and it seems as part of it is being cut off or off center. I've tried adding `google.maps.event.triggerr(map, 'resize')` and it is still cutting off. Any ideas?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 var map;
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 15,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$lat?>, <?=$long?>),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);
      }
      //google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the div displaying your map has a size before you trigger the resize event.